# winjs.xhr and function call in winjs

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

**Scenario:** I am trying to call a webservice which returns the results in json, the logic should be very straight forward.

I call a webservice url in `WinJS.xhr()` add a then function to process the result, here i am trying to bind it to a list.

I am using the below but i am not getting anything displayed what am i doing wrong here?

Can some one tell me how to call a winjs.xhr() from a function and return some object which i can bind as i am trying below?

```
    function getData() {
        return WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23windows8&rpp=10" })
    }    
    function myFunc() {
        getData().then(function (xhr) {
            var jsondata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
            return jsondata;
            // ...do something with the data when it arrives...
        }, function (err) {
            // ...do something with the error
        });
    }     

 var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(myFunc());

    //var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);
    var publicMembers =
        {
            itemList: dataList
        };
    WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExample", publicMembers);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ctor for `WinJS.Binding.List` accepts a list or array as the initial contents of the list. Your `myFunc()` will return nothing. You can set up an empty list using

```
var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List()
```

and export it as you currently do.
Then, in `myFunc()`, placed below the `dataList` declaration, you can just add items to the list. For example, assuming that `jsondata` parses into an array:

```
function myFunc() {
    getData().then(function (xhr) {
        var jsondata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        jsondata.forEach(function(entry) { dataList.push(entry); });
    }, function (err) {
        // ...do something with the error
    });
}
```

Edit: I also assume you have bound `dataList.dataSource` to the `itemDataSource` of a `WinJS.UI.ListView` and set a matching `itemTemplate` property or render function.